# Stuff function in T-SQL to concatenate values replicating n times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
select    
    TM.Tranaction_Slno,TT.Location,
    [Container Number] = stuff((select ',' + TD.Container_Number 
                                from Transaction_Data 
                                for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')   
from 
    Transaction_Master TM         
inner join 
    Transaction_Data TD on TD.Tranaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno        
left join 
    Transaction_Track TT on TT.Transaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno 
where 
    TM.Tranaction_Slno = 1770575
```

I'm getting output with concatenated values replicating n times. the output is attached below:

[image]

This screenshot shows without using stuff function:

[image]

I want a output like this:

```
Transaction_Slno    Location    Container_Number
----------------------------------------------------------
1770575             CUSTOM       ZIMU1374787,TRHU3437713
1770575             ZERO         ZIMU1374787,TRHU3437713
1770575             CFS          ZIMU1374787,TRHU3437713
```

Comment: You have to join your subquery with your main query to get related data

Comment: @JaimeDrq can please say with example query

Comment: Sorry friend but not I am on the cell phone and it’s very difficult to write queries from here. But you should join your subquery in the stuff function with your main query and if you want just the distinct values without duplicates use distinct inside the subquery

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't do string "concatenation". You might want to actually read [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @JaimeDrq it's ok thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the code with distinct and also you need to add a where condition in the xml path code

```
select  
        TM.Tranaction_Slno,TT.Location,
        [Container Number] = stuff((select distinct  ',' + Container_Number 
                                    from Transaction_Data TD1 
                                    where TD1.Transaction_Slno=TD.Transaction_Slno
                                    and  TD1.Location=TD.Location
                                    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')   
    from 
        Transaction_Master TM         
    inner join 
        Transaction_Data TD on TD.Tranaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno  and  TM.Location=TD.Location      
    left join 
        Transaction_Track TT on TT.Transaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno and  TM.Location=TT.Location
    where 
        TM.Tranaction_Slno = 1770575
```

Comment: It's not working. showing invalid column name for TD1.Transaction_Slno=TD.Transaction_Slno

Comment: your transcation_data table contains the column transaction_slno right?

Comment: I don't see why that error comes, it states taht column is missing in that table, can you try the query again?

Comment: Can you try now, I added the location

Comment: If this solved your issue you can select as accepted answer, cheers happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using group concatenation logic as follows:

```
SELECT
    tm.Transaction_Slno,
    tt.Location,
    [Container Number] = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + td.Container_Number
        FROM Transaction_Data td
        WHERE td.Transaction_Slno = tm.Transaction_Slno
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Transaction_Master tm
INNER JOIN Transaction_Track tt
    ON tt.Transaction_Slno = tm.Transaction_Slno
ORDER BY
    tm.Transaction_Slno;
```

The main logical problem with your current call to `STUFF` is that it does not correlate the query against the `Transaction_Data` table to the other table(s) involved in the query.

Comment: Looks well, maybe just a distinct missing in the subquery?

Comment: @JaimeDrq I actually don't see any duplicate data being removed...am I missing something?